# Updating Null records of a table by invoking stored procedure throws error 'Subquery returned more than one value'

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update all null values of a column with Uuid (generated with the help of a stored procedure `GetOptimizedUuid`). While doing so I am getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

I could understand the causes of error but none of my fix helped out.

I tried out with some loops but it doesn't fix

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @no INT;
    DECLARE @i INT;

    SET @no = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1)
    SET @i = 0;

    WHILE @i < @no  
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TempUuid TABLE(SeqUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, OptimizedUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

        INSERT INTO @TempUuid
            EXECUTE [Sample].[dbo].[GetOptimizedUuid]

        UPDATE table1  
        SET col2 = (SELECT OptimizedUuid FROM @TempUuid) 
        WHERE col2 IS NULL;

        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
END
```

Help me to sort out this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're doing - what do you need to call this `GetOptimizedUuid` stored procedure? Can't you just use `NEWID()` to get a new GUID?

Anyway - assuming you *have* to call this stored procedure, I assume you'd call it **once** before the loop, to get the ID's you need - and then you get the top (1) UUID from the table and update one row in your database table - and then you also need to **remove** that UUID that you've just used from the temp table, otherwise you keep re-using the same ID over and over again....

Try something like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @no INT;
    DECLARE @i INT;

    SET @no = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1)
    SET @i = 0;

    -- define and fill the table *ONCE* and *BEFORE* the loop
    DECLARE @TempUuid TABLE(SeqUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, OptimizedUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

    INSERT INTO @TempUuid
        EXECUTE [Sample].[dbo].[GetOptimizedUuid]

    -- declare a UUID to use
    DECLARE @NewUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    WHILE @i < @no  
    BEGIN
        -- get the first UUID from the temp table
        SELECT TOP (1) @NewUuid = OptimizedUuid
        FROM @TempUuid;

        -- update your table
        UPDATE table1  
        SET col2 = @NewUuid
        WHERE col2 IS NULL;

        -- *REMOVE* that UUID that you've used from the table
        DELETE FROM @TempUuid
        WHERE OptimizedUuid = @NewUuid;

        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
END
```

Comment: For my case I will be updating it with V1 GUID which is returned by GetOptimizedUuid SP, Thanks for your help!